# Minted doesn't work properly: random characters in code

Tags: highlighting, minted, pygments

I'm trying to get the minted package to work with a simple example code (java) on macOS:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{minted}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\begin{document}

\begin{minted}[frame=single,linenos,mathescape]{java}
public class Fibonacci {

  // The golden ratio $\phi = \frac{1 + \sqrt{5}}{2}$.
  public static final double PHI = (1.0 + Math.sqrt(5.0)) / 2.0;

  public static double fibonacci(long n) {
    if (n &lt; 0) throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    return Math.floor(Math.pow(PHI, n) / Math.sqrt(5.0) + 0.5);
  }

}
\end{minted}

\end{document}
```

I'm using TexShop with standard LaTeX compiler. My output looks weird and isn't highlighted at all. There are some weird characters added which I also get in the \PY command in the pygmentize output .tex-file when using it from the terminal. Using the .tex-file created directly with pygmentize gives the same output as using minted in latex.

My output:
[image]

What am I doing wrong? It worked perfectly 5 months ago.

Comment: Works for me, no strange `o`.

Comment: @Marvin Kropp: See `pygstyle` files in a directory `_minted-foo`.

Comment: @Akira Kakuto: Thanks a lot! SOLUTION: Just deleted the `_minted-foo` folder. Seems to be an interference with previous compilations.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because it was caused by some old files which simply needed to be deleted.

Comment: This question and comments just saved my sanity. I would never have thought to delete that troublesome folder without this post.